# shell scripting to fetch the file contents

Tags: linux, shell, awk

a log file get generated every minute in directory called "data_logs"

log file name :

```
abc.log.2019041607
abc.log.2019041608..
```

contents of the log file like this

```
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1

R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:0
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:0
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:0
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:0 
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:0

k_MT|D:1234|ID:414|S:1
k_MT|D:1234|ID:414|S:1
k_MT|D:1235|ID:413|S:1
k_MT|D:1235|ID:413|S:1
```

I am writting a shell script, which when executed it look for the files which gets created in last 5 minutes(Last 5 files, 1 file gets created every minute), open each file one by one and do process, i.e create a output.txt file which contains, R_MT|D:1234|ID:413 for this combination total count having 's' as 0 gets stored in "submited" column, 's'=1 gets stored in notsubmitted column

my output.txt need to look like this:

```
Type, Number,ID,submitted,notsubmitted
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413,5,10
R_MT,D:1234,ID:414,0,2
R_MT,D:1235,ID:413,0,2
```

I have used this to get the submitted and notsubmitted values:

```
zcat abc.log.2019041607.gz |grep "R_MT"|awk -F"|" '{print $2","$3","$4}'|sort|uniq -c
      5 D:1234,ID:413,S:0
     10 D:1234,ID:413,S:1
      2 D:1234,ID:414,S:1
      2 D:1235,ID:413,S:1
```

by above command i am getting the count but i am not getting how can I assign it to a variable so that i can write into the fields "submitted" and "notsubmitted" in the output file, and I am not getting how to obtain the last 5 minutes files?

please help me in this thanks alot!

Comment: The last 5 files might be found with `find datalogs -type f -name "abc*" -mmin -5`.

Comment: I think the `k_MT` fields should be copied to `R_MT` fields for the results `_MT,D:1234,ID:414,0,2` and `R_MT,D:1235,ID:413,0,2`.

Comment: Already asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/534122/133219 - please don't multi-post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross posted https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534122/shell-scripting-to-fetch-the-file-contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one file:
First make the stream easy for processing with `awk` (it could be done all in `awk`, for a slightly better performance):

```
sed -nr 's/\|/,/g;s/(^R_MT,.*),S:([^ ]) *$/\1 \2/p' <(zcat abc.log.2019041607.gz)
```

Result (after adding the lines I suggested as a comment to your question)

```
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 0
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 0
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 0
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 0
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 0
R_MT,D:1234,ID:414 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:414 1
R_MT,D:1235,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1235,ID:413 1
```

And now count them in `awk`, using array a for the fieldnames.

```
sed -nr 's/\|/,/g;s/(^R_MT,.*),S:([^ ]) *$/\1 \2/p' <(zcat abc.log.2019041607.gz) |
   awk '{a[$1]; if ($2>0) notsub[$1]++; else submit[$1]++;}
        END {for (i in a) print i "," submit[i]+0 "," notsub[i]+0;}
       '
```

For 5 files first determine how you want the results.
Each file a different outputfile: use a loop like

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
   ... <( zcat "${filename}") ...
done < <(find datalogs -type f -name "abc*" -mmin -5)
```

Results from the 5 files added to one sum

```
... <( find datalogs -type f -name "abc*" -mmin -5 -exec zcat {} \;) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this command

```
find . -name 'abc.log.*' -mmin -5
```

. can be changed to any path you want. 
-mmin represents the last modified 5 minutes ago

This command will result in a list of files created in the past 5 minutes. Then save into a temp. file and read one line at a time to process those file to your  liking.

Comment: Use `-mmin -5` for this part of the solution.

Comment: Thanks @WalterA I have updated it now